# Scanning all the siunits in a document

Tags: table-of-contents, siunitx

When the macro `\tableofcontents`, is given it takes all the chapters, parts, sections, ... and generates the Table of Contents for the Whole Document. Even the `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` do that. Now, I have a set of `siunits` in my document used with a tcolorbox modification `\begin{siunit}...\end{siunit}`, How do I define a command that scans all these `siunit`s envronments and generates a page of all the siunits used.

Here is the Source Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\gauss{G}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{empheq}
%%--------tcolorbox setting for the SI Units display---------%%
\newtcolorbox{siunit}{enhanced,
  colframe=red!60!black,colback=yellow!50!white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt,
  drop fuzzy shadow,before=\begin{center},after=\end{center},hbox}
%\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
%  colframe=red!60!black,colback=yellow!50!white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt,
%  drop fuzzy shadow}}
\newtcbox{\picturebox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,
  enhanced,watermark graphics=example-grid-100x100bp.jpg,% from package mwe
  colback=white,frame hidden,boxrule=0pt,arc=10pt,
  watermark stretch=1.00,watermark opacity=0.4,#1}
%%--------Chapter and Section headings display------------%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large\filleft} %\centering doesn't work only \filleft
{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filright}
[\vspace{2ex}
\titlerule]

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
{\LARGE\bfseries}
{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
{-2.15pc}{3.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex minus .1ex}

\makeatletter

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
\headrule \sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle]
{\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}

\end{titlepage}
\mainmatter
\include{magnetic}
\end{document}
```

magnetic.tex:

```
\chapter{Magnetic Materials}
\section{Introduction}
Magnetic materials have had various applications in ancient and modern society. A magnetic compass made of lodestone (magnetite) was used for navigation since the north pole of a compass point toward the south pole of Earth's magnetic field. In the modern era, magnetism and magnetic materials find applications in various fields.

\section{Origin of Magnetic properties of\\ materials}
Magnetic properties of materials have their origin in :
\begin{enumerate}
\item Permanent magnetic moments of their atoms and$/$or
\item Induced magnetic moments due to the change of motion of the electric charges of the atoms in an external magnetic field.
\end{enumerate}
The magnetic moments of atomic nuclei are generally neglected as they are very small.

\paragraph{Permanent magnetic moment of atoms}is due to the orbital and spin motions of unpaired electrons (i.e., electrons in the incompletely filled valence shell). Electrons in completely filled valence shells have no magnetic moment.(Eg. He, Ne, Ar etc). Some of the important terms in the study of magnetic materials is given below.

\paragraph{Magnetic fields}are generated by movement of electric charges. \textit{\bfseries Magnetic field} is the region of space where moving charges, current carrying elements or other magnetic objects will experience a force.

\paragraph{Magnetic moment}of a magnet is a quantity that determines the force the magnet can exert on electric currents and the torque that a magnetic field will exert on it. A loop of electric current generates a \textit{magnetic dipole field}. \textit{Magnitude} of the magnetic dipole moment is the product of the current and the area of the loop. Magnetic dipole is often represented schematically as an arrow. The head of the arrow is the North pole.\par
\begin{siunit}
SI unit :  Ampere. square metre (\si{\ampere\square\meter})
\end{siunit}

\paragraph{Magnetic Field lines} run from the North pole to the South pole.
\paragraph{Magnetic Flux}The group of magnetic field lines emitted outward from the north pole of a magnet is called \textit{magnetic flux}.\par
\begin{siunit}
SI~unit :  Weber (\si{\weber})
\end{siunit}
One weber is equal to $1$ x $10^8$ magnetic field lines. Direction of flux at any point in space indicates the direction of force that would be experienced by a North pole placed at that point.

\paragraph{Intensity of Magnetization M}A Material with a net (nonzero) magnetic moment is magnetized. \textit{Intensity of Magnetization M} is the magnetic moment per unit volume within the material.\par
\begin{siunit}
SI unit :  Ampere per metre (\si{\ampere\per\meter})
\end{siunit}
M depends on the following:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Number density of magnetic dipole moments within material.
\item Magnitude of the magnetic dipole moments.
\item The arrangement of the magnetic dipoles within the material and so on.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{Magnetization M}in materials mainly arises from spins of unpaired electrons within the material and to a lesser extent from their orbital motion.

\section{Magnetic field}
A \textbf{magnetic field} is a field of force produced by moving electric charges, by electric fields varying with time and by the \textbf{intrinsic} magnetic field of elementary particles due to their spin. Magnetic field is a vector field and is most commonly defined in terms of the Lorentz force that it exerts on moving electric charges. The magnetic field can be visualized as magnetic field lines.\par
There are two separate but closely related fields to which the name 'magnetic field' can refer:
A magnetic \textbf{B} field called \textit{magnetic induction} or \textit{magnetic flux density} \par
%{\centering \tcbox{SI unit :  tesla, T}} %%tcolorbox not properly aligned when using \centering -- thought will complete in a single line
\begin{siunit}
SI unit :  tesla, \si{\tesla}
\end{siunit}
and  a magnetic \textbf{H} field called \textit{magetic field strength} or \textit{magnetizing field}\par
%{\centering \tcbox{SI unit :  Ampere per metre $A.m^{-1}$}}
\begin{siunit}
SI unit :  Ampere per metre (\si{\ampere\per\meter})
\end{siunit}
Magnetic field strength \textbf{H} is measured in $A/m$, and magnetic flux density \textbf{B}, measured in $Nm/A$, also called tesla (T).

\paragraph{Magnetic flux density or magnetic induction B}\textit{Magnetic Flux density} \textbf{B} is the amount of magnetism induced in a body and it is a function of the \textit{magnetizing force} \textbf{H}.
The \textit{magnetic induction}, \textbf{B} is defined as the amount of magnetic flux through a unit area taken perpendicular to the direction of the magnetic flux.
\begin{siunit}
\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
SI unit  : Weber per metre square (\si{\weber\per\square\meter}) or tesla (\si{\tesla})
\par
CGS unit  : gauss ($\SI{1}{\tesla} = \SI{10000}{\gauss}$)
\end{minipage}
\end{siunit}

\paragraph{Manetic field strength, H}Magnetic field strength \textbf{H} is the amount of magnetizing force. Magnetic field strength is a vector quantity whose magnitude is the strength of a magnetic field at a point in the direction of the magnetic field at that point.
\begin{siunit}
SI~unit  : Ampere~per~metre (\si{\ampere\per\meter})
\end{siunit}

\section{Relation between B and H}
\textit{In free space or outside of a material (i.e., in vacuum) the \textbf{B} and \textbf{H} fields are indistinguishable (they only differ by a multiplicative constant).}
\begin{gather*}
B = \mu_{0}.H \quad \text{(in vaccum)} \\
\mu_{0}   \rightarrow \text{magnetic permeability of free space (vacuum)}
\end{gather*}
where $\mu_{0} = 4\pi~\text{x}~10^7 N.A^{-2}~(H.m^{-1})$ \par
Inside magnetic material,  $B = \mu.H = \mu_{0}.H + \mu_{0}.M $ where $\mu$ is the \\ \textit{magnetic permeability of medium}.
```

Comment: Orthogonal comment: The idea of using SI units is to remove ambiguities. So if you use SI units in your document you shouldn't be explaining them, since they should be according to the standards

Comment: @percusse: Perhaps it is sometimes better to explain some features/definitions more than once, depending on the recepients of the document.

Comment: @subhamsoni: Please have a look on the `tcolorbox` manual, on page 75 in my version 2.60, the explanation about generating lists of used `tcolorbox`es, so this should be possible for your `siunit` boxes as well.

Comment: @subhamsoni: Addendum: On the latest version (2.80) it is page 79, to be found here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I referred the document. But I couldn't follow it. I would be happy if you give a small MWE

Comment: I have a solution, but it needs to use arguments to your `siunit` box environments. Do you stick to `\begin{siunit}...\end{siunit}` or would something like `\SiunitBox[options]{SiUnit list entry}{Siunit content}` also do?

Comment: If it is able to create a list then anything is fine for me :) @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @subhamsoni: Well, there is one issue: What should be listed actually? The name of the quantity (say, magnetic flux) and its SI unit, (i.e. Weber) for example?

Comment: Exactly @ChristianHupfer. You have got it right :)

Comment: @subhamsoni: Please give me some time to make some changes ;-)

Comment: Sure :) @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Make sure you don't create more confusion than clarity :P

Comment: @percusse: I teach pupils every day, believe me, it is necessary to say/repeat wellknown content more than once ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I introduced a wrapper command, for the name of the quantity and its unit, to be written to the `listofsiunits` - toc file.

Instead of `\begin{siunit}...\end{siunit}` use `\SiunitBox{Magnetic Flux}{Weber}` instead. The first parameter is optional and deals with settings of the colorbox. In the example, my changes have a green frame in the output.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\gauss{G}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{empheq}
%%--------tcolorbox setting for the SI Units display---------%%


% Wrapper for siunitbox%
\newenvironment{siunit}[2][]{%
\begin{siunitbox}[#1]{#2}
SI~unit : #2%
\end{siunitbox}}{% Other start code
}{% Other end code
}%

\newrobustcmd{\SiunitBox}[3][]{%
  \begin{siunitbox}[#1]{#2: #3}
    SI~unit : #3%
  \end{siunitbox}
}

\newcounter{siunitboxcounter}

\newtcolorbox[use counter={siunitboxcounter},number within=section,list inside={siunitbox}]{siunitbox}[2][]{enhanced,%
  colframe=red!60!black,colback=yellow!50!white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt,
  drop fuzzy shadow,before=\begin{center},after=\end{center},hbox,list entry={\protect\textbf{#2}},#1}
%\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
%  colframe=red!60!black,colback=yellow!50!white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt,
%  drop fuzzy shadow}}
\newtcbox{\picturebox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,
  enhanced,watermark graphics=example-grid-100x100bp.jpg,% from package mwe
  colback=white,frame hidden,boxrule=0pt,arc=10pt,
  watermark stretch=1.00,watermark opacity=0.4,#1}
%%--------Chapter and Section headings display------------%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large\filleft} %\centering doesn't work only \filleft
{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filright}
[\vspace{2ex}
\titlerule]

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
{\LARGE\bfseries}
{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
{-2.15pc}{3.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex minus .1ex}

\makeatletter

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
\headrule \sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle]
{\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}

\end{titlepage}



\tcblistof{siunitbox}{List of SI units}
\mainmatter
\include{magnetic}
\end{document}
```

**magnetic.tex**

```
\chapter{Magnetic Materials}
\section{Introduction}
Magnetic materials have had various applications in ancient and modern society. A magnetic compass made of lodestone (magnetite) was used for navigation since the north pole of a compass point toward the south pole of Earth's magnetic field. In the modern era, magnetism and magnetic materials find applications in various fields.

\section{Origin of Magnetic properties of\\ materials}
Magnetic properties of materials have their origin in :
\begin{enumerate}
\item Permanent magnetic moments of their atoms and$/$or
\item Induced magnetic moments due to the change of motion of the electric charges of the atoms in an external magnetic field.
\end{enumerate}
The magnetic moments of atomic nuclei are generally neglected as they are very small.

\paragraph{Permanent magnetic moment of atoms}is due to the orbital and spin motions of unpaired electrons (i.e., electrons in the incompletely filled valence shell). Electrons in completely filled valence shells have no magnetic moment.(Eg. He, Ne, Ar etc). Some of the important terms in the study of magnetic materials is given below.

\paragraph{Magnetic fields}are generated by movement of electric charges. \textit{\bfseries Magnetic field} is the region of space where moving charges, current carrying elements or other magnetic objects will experience a force.

\paragraph{Magnetic moment}of a magnet is a quantity that determines the force the magnet can exert on electric currents and the torque that a magnetic field will exert on it. A loop of electric current generates a \textit{magnetic dipole field}. \textit{Magnitude} of the magnetic dipole moment is the product of the current and the area of the loop. Magnetic dipole is often represented schematically as an arrow. The head of the arrow is the North pole.\par
%\SiunitBox{SI unit :  Ampere. square metre (\si{\ampere\square\meter})}

\begin{siunit}{Ampere. square metre (\si{\ampere\square\meter})}
%SI~unit :  Ampere. square metre (\si{\ampere\square\meter})
\end{siunit}

\SiunitBox[colframe=green]{Magnetic Moment}{Ampere. square metre (\si{\ampere\square\meter})}


\paragraph{Magnetic Field lines} run from the North pole to the South pole.
\paragraph{Magnetic Flux}The group of magnetic field lines emitted outward from the north pole of a magnet is called \textit{magnetic flux}.\par
\begin{siunit}{Weber (\si{\weber})}
\end{siunit}

\SiunitBox[colframe=green]{Magnetic Flux}{Weber (\si{\weber})}

One weber is equal to $1$ x $10^8$ magnetic field lines. Direction of flux at any point in space indicates the direction of force that would be experienced by a North pole placed at that point.

\paragraph{Intensity of Magnetization M}A Material with a net (nonzero) magnetic moment is magnetized. \textit{Intensity of Magnetization M} is the magnetic moment per unit volume within the material.\par
\begin{siunit}{Ampere per metre(\si{\ampere\per\meter})}
\end{siunit}
M depends on the following:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Number density of magnetic dipole moments within material.
\item Magnitude of the magnetic dipole moments.
\item The arrangement of the magnetic dipoles within the material and so on.
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{Magnetization M}in materials mainly arises from spins of unpaired electrons within the material and to a lesser extent from their orbital motion.

\section{Magnetic field}
A \textbf{magnetic field} is a field of force produced by moving electric charges, by electric fields varying with time and by the \textbf{intrinsic} magnetic field of elementary particles due to their spin. Magnetic field is a vector field and is most commonly defined in terms of the Lorentz force that it exerts on moving electric charges. The magnetic field can be visualized as magnetic field lines.\par
There are two separate but closely related fields to which the name 'magnetic field' can refer:
A magnetic \textbf{B} field called \textit{magnetic induction} or \textit{magnetic flux density} \par
%{\centering \tcbox{SI unit :  tesla, T}} %%tcolorbox not properly aligned when using \centering -- thought will complete in a single line
\begin{siunit}{tesla, \si{\tesla}}
\end{siunit}%
and  a magnetic \textbf{H} field called \textit{magetic field strength} or \textit{magnetizing field}\par
%{\centering \tcbox{SI unit :  Ampere per metre $A.m^{-1}$}}
\begin{siunit}{SI unit :  Ampere per metre (\si{\ampere\per\meter})}
\end{siunit}
Magnetic field strength \textbf{H} is measured in $A/m$, and magnetic flux density \textbf{B}, measured in $Nm/A$, also called tesla (T).

\paragraph{Magnetic flux density or magnetic induction B}\textit{Magnetic Flux density} \textbf{B} is the amount of magnetism induced in a body and it is a function of the \textit{magnetizing force} \textbf{H}.
The \textit{magnetic induction}, \textbf{B} is defined as the amount of magnetic flux through a unit area taken perpendicular to the direction of the magnetic flux.
%\begin{siunit}
%\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
%SI unit  : Weber per metre square (\si{\weber\per\square\meter}) or tesla (\si{\tesla})
%\par
%CGS unit  : gauss ($\SI{1}{\tesla} = \SI{10000}{\gauss}$)
%\end{minipage}
%\end{siunit}

\paragraph{Manetic field strength, H}Magnetic field strength \textbf{H} is the amount of magnetizing force. Magnetic field strength is a vector quantity whose magnitude is the strength of a magnetic field at a point in the direction of the magnetic field at that point.
\begin{siunit}{Ampere~per~metre (\si{\ampere\per\meter})}
\end{siunit}

\section{Relation between B and H}
\textit{In free space or outside of a material (i.e., in vacuum) the \textbf{B} and \textbf{H} fields are indistinguishable (they only differ by a multiplicative constant).}
\begin{gather*}
B = \mu_{0}.H \quad \text{(in vaccum)} \\
\mu_{0}   \rightarrow \text{magnetic permeability of free space (vacuum)}
\end{gather*}
where $\mu_{0} = 4\pi~\text{x}~10^7 N.A^{-2}~(H.m^{-1})$ \par
Inside magnetic material,  $B = \mu.H = \mu_{0}.H + \mu_{0}.M $ where $\mu$ is the \\ \textit{magnetic permeability of medium}.
```

[image]

**Note**

Do not use `\begin{siunitbox}...` directly, it does not set the quantity to the list file.

Comment: How to remove the equation numbers on the left in the list?

Comment: @subhamsoni: I removed the `\numberline` statement in the `list entry=...` statement

Comment: @subhamsoni: There was a siunitbox with two contents (about magnetic flux density units tesla and gauss ... this is not possible this way with my command) Perhaps you define a similar environment and make a list of those non siunit boxes as well